# Docker MySQL-server SegFault on container start up

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm using `mysql/mysql-server:5.7` in a docker-compose.yml file. After recreating containers I'm all of a sudden getting the following error.

```
mysql-1  | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.41-1.2.11-server
mysql-1  | [Entrypoint] Initializing database
mysql-1  | /entrypoint.sh: line 230:    41 Segmentation fault      "$@" --user=$MYSQLD_USER --initialize-insecure --default-time-zone=+00:00
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to debug this? I can't think of anything specific that I've done recently that would cause my container to not be able to initialize.

I've nuked the volumes and images and still to no avail.

Docker version: Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41

I have coworkers that are on Docker 25.0.2 and this compose file works fine for them. Let me know what other information might be helpful to track down what might be going on.

Comment: Not entirely sure what we (or you) can do about this from a **programming** point of view, Your are getting segfault error from compiled applications.